# Angular modal dialog isn't working and hides button/footer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, frontend

I'm creating a basic web application using Angular. I want to create scrum board with 3 columns.

In the first column, I want to create a button which opens a modal dialog as soon as you click it. The problem is, as soon as implement the modal dialog into the button, the button goes invisible and even the footer is gone.

Here is everything:

`body.component.html`:

```
<div class="board-container">
    <div class="column" id="offen">
        <app-task-form></app-task-form>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="bearbeitung">
        <!-- Hier kommen Aufgaben in der Kategorie "In Bearbeitung" -->
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="abgeschlossen">
        <!-- Hier kommen Aufgaben in der Kategorie "Abgeschlossen" -->
    </div>
```

`task-form.component.html`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="taskTitle" placeholder="Enter task title" />
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
```

`task-form.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { ModalComponent } from '../modal/modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-form',
  templateUrl: './task-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-form.component.css']
})
export class TaskFormComponent {
  taskTitle: string = ''; // Eine Eigenschaft, um den Aufgabentitel zu speichern

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openModal() {
    this.dialog.open(ModalComponent);
  }
}
```

`modal.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent {

}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // Importiere FormsModule


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { TaskFormComponent } from './task-form/task-form.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TaskFormComponent,
    ModalComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule, // Füge FormsModule hinzu
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look in your browser developer tools, the console says:
"ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[MatDialog -> MatDialog]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!"

This error means you haven't included the Material Dialog module in your application, so there is no provider.

In your app.module.ts, you have to add MatDialogModule to your imports.

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // Importiere FormsModule


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { TaskFormComponent } from './task-form/task-form.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TaskFormComponent,
    ModalComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule, // Füge FormsModule hinzu
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDialogModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you, im extremly new to webdevelopment and i didnt even know that i could debug it like that. Thank you!